# Simple Jquery selector

Tags: jquery

Does anyone see why this jquery click function would not work? It is not apparent to me why it would not.  Thank you !

Here is my selector

```
$(".ILikeItImg").click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

Here is the tag I want the click function to happen on.

```
<img alt="I Like It" class="ILikeItImg" src="../QuickTagILikeIt_24.png"  />
```

Comment: Did you register it on `$(document).ready`? Can you reproduce the problem in a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/Jhv8C/ Works for me, do you included properly your jQuery library? Wrapped the all inside a `ready function` / your code is before the ending `</body>` tag? ...

Comment: did i register it on $(document).ready = don't think so, i'll check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ywkhh/1/) !!

And the code

```
<img alt="I Like It" class="ILikeItImg" src="http://www.allaboutdogsandcats.com/images/cat22.jpg" />​

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".ILikeItImg").click(function() {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });

});​
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to put this within a ready():

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".ILikeItImg").click(function() {
         alert("Handler for .click() called.");
         });
  });
```

Comment: You can also use the shorter `$(function() {`.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code inside $(document).ready()
Like

```
$(function(){
$(".ILikeItImg").click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
});
```